# How to use ObservableLists in JavaFX

Tags: model-view-controller, binding, javafx, observable, observablelist

I'm trying to use ObservableLists to help me orchestrate an MVC framework in a new application I'm building. I have a LineData object that contains the information necessary to draw a line on screen, and I want to maintain a list of LineData in the backend of my program. Then, I want corresponding lines to be drawn on screen via the front end whenever the list of LineData is drawn in the backend. I believe that to do this, I need to have a list in the front end that is bound to the list in the backend, and then I need to have some sort of listener on this list that triggers new data to be turned into lines and drawn? I'm just confused on how to do this -- any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this "by hand", registering a listener with the `ObservableList<LineData>` and adding or removing elements from the child list of a `Pane` as needed. So something like

```
public class Model {

    // ...

    public ObservableList<LineData> getLineData() { ... }

    // ...

}
```

And then

```
public class MyController {

    Model model ;

    @FXML
    private Pane pane ; // contains lines...

    public void initialize() {
        model.getLineData().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change change) -> {
            while (change.next()) { 
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    change.getAddedSubList().stream()
                        .map(this::createLineForLineData)
                        .forEach(pane.getChildren()::add);
                } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    change.getRemoved().forEach(lineData -> 
                        pane.getChildren().removeIf((Line line) -> lineMatchesLineData(line, lineData));
                }
            }
        });

        // ...

    }


    // ...

    private Line createLineForLineData(LineData lineData) {
        // create Line matching data in lineData and return it
    }

    private boolean lineMatchesLineData(Line line, LineData lineData) {
        // return true if line's state matches data in lineData, false otherwise
    }
}
```

Note though that the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework has built-in functionality for this:

```
public class MyController {

    Model model ;

    @FXML
    private Pane pane ;

    public void initialize() {
        Bindings.bindContent(pane.getChildren(),
            EasyBind.map(model.getLineData(), this::createLineForLineData));

        // ...
    }

    private Line createLineForLineData(LineData lineData) { ... }

}
```